# Modal View Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, flip

I am using the following code in Xcode to horizontally flip between 2 views in an iPhone app

```
 -(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender{
    Algorithm2ViewController *Algorithm2ViewControllergo = [[Algorithm2ViewController    alloc]
                                                            initWithNibName:@"Algorithm2ViewController"                                                    bundle:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                           forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:Algorithm2ViewControllergo.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

after the first flip I get an image of the coming view in the background before the completion of the flip how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out in the second view add the following code

```
-(IBAction)switchView2:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *SecondViewControllergo = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithNibName:@"SecondView"
                                                    bundle:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                           forView:self.view.superview cache:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:SecondViewControllergo.view];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    [SecondViewControllergo release];


}
```

The remove from superview line will remove the background image